# Mercurial usage to merge multiple heads

Tags: mercurial

I'm mercurial newbie and want to learn how to use my [repository](http://montao.googlecode.com). Can you tell me how to merge my friend's work with mine? Thanks

```
$ hg update tip
abort: crosses branches (merge branches or use --clean to discard changes)

$ hg heads
changeset:   265:ac5d3c3a03ac
tag:         tip
user:        roberto.cr
date:        Thu Oct 06 07:32:15 2011 +0000
summary:     fixing "redirects" links

changeset:   261:6acd1aaef950
user:        niklasro
date:        Thu Oct 06 07:53:19 2011 +0000
summary:     auth backend + js

$ hg update
abort: crosses branches (merge branches or use --clean to discard changes)
```

Could I use hg resolve?

```
$ hg resolve
abort: no files or directories specified; use --all to remerge all file

$ hg glog | more
@  changeset:   266:2bf5b62720fc
|  tag:         tip
|  parent:      261:6acd1aaef950
|  user:        niklasro
|  date:        Thu Oct 06 12:48:20 2011 +0000
|  summary:     added
|
| o  changeset:   265:ac5d3c3a03ac
| |  user:        roberto.cr
| |  date:        Thu Oct 06 07:32:15 2011 +0000
| |  summary:     fixing "redirects" links
| |
| o  changeset:   264:2fd0bf24e90f
| |  user:        roberto.cr
| |  date:        Thu Oct 06 07:29:58 2011 +0000
| |  summary:     fixing "redirects" links
| |
| o  changeset:   263:29a373aae81e
| |  user:        roberto.cr
| |  date:        Thu Oct 06 07:25:05 2011 +0000
| |  summary:     fixing "redirects" links
| |
| o  changeset:   262:d75cd4d3e77a
| |  parent:      260:dfb54b99f84d
| |  user:        roberto.cr
| |  date:        Thu Oct 06 07:24:55 2011 +0000
| |  summary:     fixing "redirects" links
| |
o |  changeset:   261:6acd1aaef950
|/   user:        niklasro
|    date:        Thu Oct 06 07:53:19 2011 +0000
|    summary:     auth backend + js
|
o  changeset:   260:dfb54b99f84d
|  user:        niklasro
|  date:        Wed Oct 05 05:34:37 2011 +0000
|  summary:     FB buggfix example.html
|
o  changeset:   259:92fb6b1bc492
|  user:        niklasro
|  date:        Thu Sep 29 16:42:33 2011 +0000
|  summary:     changes
```

The solution was `hg revert -a` and it looks like a success now

```
$ hg glog | more
@    changeset:   267:3b2bb6de33eb
|\   tag:         tip
| |  parent:      266:2bf5b62720fc
| |  parent:      265:ac5d3c3a03ac
| |  user:        niklasro
| |  date:        Thu Oct 06 16:06:21 2011 +0000
| |  summary:     merge
| |
| o  changeset:   266:2bf5b62720fc
| |  parent:      261:6acd1aaef950
| |  user:        niklasro
| |  date:        Thu Oct 06 12:48:20 2011 +0000
| |  summary:     added
| |
o |  changeset:   265:ac5d3c3a03ac
| |  user:        roberto.cr
| |  date:        Thu Oct 06 07:32:15 2011 +0000
| |  summary:     fixing "redirects" links
| |
o |  changeset:   264:2fd0bf24e90f
| |  user:        roberto.cr
| |  date:        Thu Oct 06 07:29:58 2011 +0000
| |  summary:     fixing "redirects" links
| |
o |  changeset:   263:29a373aae81e
| |  user:        roberto.cr
| |  date:        Thu Oct 06 07:25:05 2011 +0000
| |  summary:     fixing "redirects" links
| |
o |  changeset:   262:d75cd4d3e77a
| |  parent:      260:dfb54b99f84d
| |  user:        roberto.cr
| |  date:        Thu Oct 06 07:24:55 2011 +0000
| |  summary:     fixing "redirects" links
| |
| o  changeset:   261:6acd1aaef950
|/   user:        niklasro
|    date:        Thu Oct 06 07:53:19 2011 +0000
|    summary:     auth backend + js
|
o  changeset:   260:dfb54b99f84d
|  user:        niklasro
|  date:        Wed Oct 05 05:34:37 2011 +0000
|  summary:     FB buggfix example.html
|
o  changeset:   259:92fb6b1bc492
|  user:        niklasro
|  date:        Thu Sep 29 16:42:33 2011 +0000
|  summary:     changes
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The basic problem here is that your working directory is not clean. Mercurial prevents people from accidentally jumping between branches with uncommitted changes as this is generally a bad idea.

Let's start with that first command:

```
$ hg update tip
abort: crosses branches (merge branches or use --clean to discard changes)
```

This is telling you two important things:

- you're trying to cross branches
- you have uncommitted changes

And that you have two options:

- merge
- use hg update --clean to lose your changes

So what are your changes? The first step is to run 'hg status'. As you say 'hg status outputs many files prepended by 1 or ?'. Well those '1s' are actually '!' indicating deleted/missing files (get a better font!). You should doublecheck against summary, which will give you output like this:

```
parent: 15200:fa6f93befffa 
 patch: use more precise pattern for diff header color styling (issue3034)
branch: default
commit: 1 deleted, 1 unknown (clean)   <- your changes
update: (current)
```

If you try to merge at this point, you'll get a message like:

```
$ hg merge stable
abort: outstanding uncommitted changes (use 'hg status' to list changes)
```

If you have changes other than missing files, you'll want to consider committing them.

If these missing files are your only changes, it's probably ok to discard them:

```
hg revert -a
```

After you've done that, you're in a state where Mercurial will let you update or merge without complaining.

Finally, you say "hg status output many files from other projects since it starts at .. The file I added is the only file that should get added.". This is a basic misunderstanding of how Mercurial works. Unlike CVS or SVN, **there is only one project** as far as Mercurial is concerned and actions (commit/update/merge/status) work on the entire project tree at once. Subdirectories are not independent projects with separate histories.

Answer (score 17):

What about merging these two heads?

```
hg merge
```

Comment: Yes that's the problem: `$ hg merge
abort: outstanding uncommitted changes (use 'hg status' to list changes)`

Comment: hg commit first, then hg merge, then (eventually) hg push

Comment: hg commit is a problem too: `$ hg commit
nothing changed` `$ hg merge
abort: outstanding uncommitted changes (use 'hg status' to list changes)` Why is it difficult?

Comment: then try hg commit <full_path_to_one_of_these_files>

Comment: `$ hg add /media/Lexar/montao/montaoproject/facebook.py`
`$ hg commit -m 'added' /media/Lexar/montao/montaoproject/facebook.py` How now? merge, push, shelve, resolve, something else?

Comment: Maybe you started hg commit before from a wrong directory. Now you should add and commit each file displayed in hg status, then merge and push.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. hg status output many files from other projects since it starts at `..` The file I added is the only file that should get added. So I try merge and my workflow is locked as usual `$ hg merge
abort: outstanding uncommitted changes (use 'hg status' to list changes)`

Comment: @Andreas - The problem was that @Niklas R was doing an `hg commit` to check if the working directory was clean, rather than using an `hg status`, as the `hg merge` suggested, not realising that deleted files also count as `uncommitted changed` to `hg merge`.

Comment: I added files (the SDK which I don't version) and I wonder which files were deleted. From the changeset log I don't see any file was deleted http://code.google.com/p/montao/source/detail?r=3b2bb6de33ebd5cccdbeea76eb3a114bc9d03a91 The problem occurred when trying to make my first merge combining a local change with a change from the web ui @googlecode. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Since this was discussed in greater depth on the [mercurial mailing list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.mercurial.general/28094), it appears that the problem was that, as [mpm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671654/mercurial-usage-to-merge-multiple-heads/7677375#7677375) suggested, the working directory wasn't clean.

To summarise that thread, before version 1.9m Mercurial would say `nothing changed` to an `hg ci` if files had just been deleted.

At 1.9 this was changed to say `nothing changed (1 missing files, see 'hg status')` to make it more explicit that while no filed had *changed*, there were still deletions and you need to tell hg what you want to do about them. Either use `hg revert -a` to discard the changes, or `hg addremove` plus `hg commit` to tell hg about the changes and commit them.

Also, as [Matt Mackall](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.mercurial.general/28108/match=merging+multiple) says:

> It might help to ask status to show only deleted files:

```
$ hg st -d
! setup.py
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. I use version 1.7.5 and this is my first time merging work with another developer who used the googlecode web ui to make his changeset. It's my fault that I didn't know what I was doing and I'm glad that version 1.9 is more informative what to do. I wan thinking of using `addremove` but that would've added the whole SDK to the project since when I make a clone I copy the GAE SDK into the project directory.

Comment: @Niklas R - Remember that you can use a .hgignore to tell mercurial to ignore (never worry about the prese4nce or absence of) files which match a pattern. Also, you may want to look into subrepo's if you have large directories full of SDK's etc. These can then be kept in their own repo and versioned, but they won't clutter up your main repo.